# airflow return a stringIO buffer

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag in airflow as such:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag
from stage import stage_data
from table_async_pg import run_async
from read_mem_view import get_view_buffer
@dag(
dag_id = "data-sync",
schedule_interval = '*/30 * * * *',
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 9, tz="Asia/Hong_Kong"),
catchup=False,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
)
def Pipeline():
    CSV_URL="myurl"
    a = stage_data()
    b = run_async()
    c = get_view_buffer(CSV_URL)

    [a,c] >> b


pipeline = Pipeline()
```

The problem happens in task `get_view_buffer` , the function look like that, it runs fine and it returns a stringio object.

```
@task
def get_view_buffer(URL):
    SKIPROWS=2
    p = Path(r'/home/d5291029/cert/truststore-prod-2.0.7.pem')
    if p.exists():
        with requests.Session() as s:
            start = time.time()
            download = s.get(URL,verify=p)
            decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
            end = time.time() - start
            print(f'time it takes to download in seconds: {end}')
            reader = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(),delimiter=',')
            output = io.StringIO()
            writer = csv.writer(output,lineterminator='\n')
            for row in reader:
                if reader.line_num > SKIPROWS:
                    writer.writerow(row)
            
            output.seek(0)
            return output
```

I get this error:

```
    [2023-03-10, 17:30:07 HKT] {python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: <_io.StringIO object at 0x7f2a70fdfee0>
    [2023-03-10, 17:30:07 HKT] {taskinstance.py:1768} ERROR - Task failed with exception
..................
      File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 153, in default
        CLASSNAME: o.__module__ + "." + o.__class__.__qualname__,
    AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

Comment: I suggest that you upgrade airflow python module as a big refactoring was done recently and the line where there's the error is gone: https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/aefa482051ec249f42095286a0fe4cf0eec1f6f4#diff-7a15a4f7b8fea7f7be350eb3809d8abfcca40419d2da36750d2d9453c7fab732

Comment: but I have latest `2.5.1` version